# Does "Paraphernalia" have a negative connotation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

By definition, the word *paraphernalia* does not portray either negative or positive emotions. Does it, in everyday usage?

In my particular case, I am making a website about programming. I have a section called
*Pleasant Programming* ***_*__*_*__**.

I thought it would be nice to have a 'p' word as the last word. However, I didn't want it to seem like negative thing. (In fact, it was supposed to be upbeat).

Comment: I think that for most people it doesn't carry any baggage at all - but my dad worked for the county Drug Abuse Control Services when I was a little kid, and for me *paraphernalia* will always mean a junkie's "works": the bent spoon, the endlessly-reused hypodermic, the tourniquet...  As I say, though, I don't think most people will have that association, and even I like to use the word to give what I'm writing a little subversive twist.

Comment: Are you talking about hardware, or about topics of concern or interest to programmers?

Comment: You have not shown what meaning you found in the dictionary. Have you checked all the meanings in the dictionaries? "trappings associated with a particular institution or activity that are **regarded as superfluous**: *the rituals and paraphernalia of government*" (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/paraphernalia)

Comment: If it refers to a section about IDEs, editors, colour pickers and such, I cannot see any issues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Paraphernalia* has a slight negative connotation in some circles because of its association with criminal possession of [drug paraphernalia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drug_paraphernalia). Otherwise, it's a good, whimsical word. I personally wouldn't worry about it, but if you have concerns, consider *potpourri* instead, especially if you're posting about trivia or other diverse topics.

Comment: -1 True, the negativity could be due the association with drugs, but that only in the phrase *drug paraphernalia*. On its own, the word has more a sense of "nuisance value" than "criminal". I'd say the word has negative connotations but not criminal.

Comment: @Kris Words are known by the company they keep, and in many communities “drug” is implicit with “paraphernalia.” See MT_Head's comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK the word 'paraphernalia' has rather strong negative connotations as it is rarely used in connection with anything not relating to drugs. It can also be used in a humorous way, but I would avoid it.

Comment: I strongly disagree. (I'm a Brit.) I didn't even think of the drug connection until I saw it mentioned. My immediate thought on reading the word *paraphernalia* was a collection of 'bits and pieces' - possibly, but certainly not necessarily, 'junk'.  Although it may not be a common usage of the word, I would have little hesitation in saying I have a lot of *computer paraphernalia*, meaning leads, connectors, disks, memory cards, etc.. It can be used in many different contexts. Although some contexts may be negative, I don't immediately consider it to have a negative connotation.

Comment: Maybe it's a generational thing, then. How old are you if that's not too rude? I'm 19

Comment: @JamesScott Let's say I remember, as a child, seeing petrol on sale at about 4/11¼d per (UK) gallon (four shillings and elevenpence-farthing) per gallon (equivalent to a little under 25p per gallon or about 5p per litre). And the answer's actually given in my profile, anyway.

Comment: @TrevorD you misspelt my name :D haha! Fair enough though; I suppose my generation would probably forge a stronger relationship between paraphernalia and drugs, than yours.

Comment: Apologies for the misspelling!